# Customizing MS Access Form field Look-up based on results from another field value on form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to develop a form on Access 365 to selects values from a series of combo boxes on the form.  The combo boxes are based on look up tables in the DB.

If I set the one field value to say carpet,
[image]

I want the Product Name field to only pop up the product names for carpet.
By default the look up list of the Product Name field will show all the possible values for all the Flooring types.

I tried to code event VB scripts to capture the Flooring Type value as a Global variable, and I am able to show a message box that the variable is available when accessing the Product Name combo box.
I would like to adjust the row source query for the Product Name query to only return the values that match the Flooring type that I selected

```
SELECT DISTINCT Flooring.[Product Name], Flooring.[Flooring Type]
FROM Flooring
WHERE Flooring.[Flooring Type] = ProdType
ORDER BY Flooring.[Product Name];

WHERE Flooring.[Flooring Type] = WHERE (((Flooring.[Flooring Type])=[Forms]![Selections Flooring Type]![Product Type])) doesnt' seem to work either
```

Issue is that the ProdType global variable that I assign in the VB script doesn't carry over to the SQL build function. I assume the VB script and SQL Designer do not talk to each other.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you actually using VBA (which ships with MSACCESS.exe) instead of VBScript? Per tag, *VBScript is not the same thing as VBA or VB.NET.*

Comment: You describe Cascading Comboboxes - a common topic. Query object cannot directly see global variables but can call VBA user function and function can return global variable content. Query object can see TempVars. Requery combobox: `Me.comboboxname.Requery`. I expect you are using VBA not VBScript - correct tag if that is the case.

Comment: Correct on VBA - (like I said newbie), I'll read up on Cascading Comboboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming VBA, consider having your query point to a user-defined function saved in a standard module (i.e., not behind form or report) of an Access project:

VBA

```vb
Public Global ProductType As String: ProductType = "some value"

Public Function GetProductType() As String
   GetProductType = ProductType
End Function
```

SQL

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Flooring.[Product Name], Flooring.[Flooring Type]
FROM Flooring
WHERE Flooring.[Flooring Type] = GetProductType();
```

However, you can simply run conditional combobox recordsources.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Flooring.[Product Name], Flooring.[Flooring Type]
FROM Flooring
WHERE (((Flooring.[Flooring Type])=[Forms]![Selections Flooring Type]![Product Type]));
```

But be sure to run `Requery` on the `AfterUpdate` event of the preceding combobox:

```vb
Private Sub Product_Type_Combo_AfterUpdate() 
   Me.Product_Name_Combo.Requery
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: Because you are using continuous forms, the `.Requery` even will run on *all* displayed, repeating comboboxes which will cause some displayed data to wipe out if condition on combobox is not met for that specific row. Rest assured the data will remain in underlying table. This may cause an undesired user experience.

One workaround includes resetting combo box back to **all** possible product types (i.e., no `WHERE` clause) when user loses focus of the Product Name combo box (`LostFocus` event) and when user navigates across rows (`CurrentRow` event). This in turn may cause you to `.Requery` to the conditional subset on the `GotFocus` event in addition to above `AfterUpdate` of preceding combobox. Basically, you will toggle between the full set and conditional recordsource queries.

Comment: That got it - had to do a wee bit of massaging to make it work - but that worked!  Thanks!